# Rect Devtools Uncaught ReferenceError: chrome is not defined

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

Im using React Native Debugger (but when using chrome devtools the app doesnt work anyway).

Ive never had problems, but today im getting

"Uncaught ReferenceError: chrome is not defined"

Error when debugger tries to connect to React. Tried uninstalling devtools, reinstalled the app, used different extensions nothing helps, my app loads, Im getting console logs but cant do anything requiring going to another screen / route. Any ideas whats causing this?

Comment: Phone restart helped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When everything else failed in rage I shut down my phone, then turned it again after some time.

It worked. Just restart your phone

Comment: Sadly, this is not going to work for me with react-native-windows targeting UWP :P